# mysql, a query from multiple unions is not executed

Tags: mysql, union

I have a query of 5 subqueries, the results of which I will use next. But making an intermediate request, checking the amount of data, I get this error in phpstorm.

> Communications link failure  The last packet successfully received from the server was 462 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 462 milliseconds ago.

my request:

```
with group_a as (select distinct p.tag_id
             from product_tag_position p
             where p.product_id in (10536839, 51807280, 58320758)
               and p.create_at between unix_timestamp('2022-07-25') and unix_timestamp('2022-08-26')),
 group_b as (select distinct p.tag_id
             from product_tag_position p
             where p.product_id in (13163479, 66357573, 66360379)
               and p.create_at between unix_timestamp('2022-07-25') and unix_timestamp('2022-08-26')),
 intersection_groups as (select group_a.tag_id
                         from group_a
                                  join group_b on group_a.tag_id = group_b.tag_id),
 only_group_a as (select distinct tag_id from group_a where tag_id not in (select tag_id from group_b)),
 only_group_b as (select distinct tag_id from group_b where tag_id not in (select tag_id from group_a))
 select count(*)
 from group_a
 union
 select count(*)
 from group_b
 union
 select count(*)
 from intersection_groups
 union
 select count(*)
 from only_group_a
 union
 select count(*)
 from only_group_b
```

the structure of the table to which the request goes.

```
create_at - integer
product_id - integer
tag_id - integer
position - smallinteger
```

if the request is not fully executed, but for example to remove the last two unions, the request will be executed, also if only the last two are executed, but together it gives an error.

what is the problem with this request? the second option works fine

```
with group_a as (select distinct p.tag_id
             from product_tag_position p
             where p.product_id in (10536839, 51807280, 58320758)
               and p.create_at between unix_timestamp('2022-07-25') and unix_timestamp('2022-08-26')),
 group_b as (select distinct p.tag_id
             from product_tag_position p
             where p.product_id in (13163479, 66357573, 66360379)
               and p.create_at between unix_timestamp('2022-07-25') and unix_timestamp('2022-08-26')),
 intersection_groups as (select group_a.tag_id
                         from group_a
                                  join group_b on group_a.tag_id = group_b.tag_id),
 only_group_a as (select a.tag_id tag_a, b.tag_id tag_b
                  from group_a a
                           left join group_b b on a.tag_id = b.tag_id),
 only_group_b as (select b.tag_id tag_b, a.tag_id tag_a
                  from group_b b
                           left join group_a a on a.tag_id = b.tag_id)
 (select count(*) from group_a)
 union
 (select count(*) from group_b)
 union
 (select count(*) from intersection_groups)
 union 
 (select count(*) from only_group_a where tag_b is null)
 union
 (select count(*) from only_group_b where tag_a is null)
```

Comment: You can only use a CTE definition _once_.  You need to redefine them.

Comment: What exact version of MySQL are you using? In versions 8.0.27 and 8.0.28 it looks like a bug, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ddca669901a21b001cc01c0a3c5c8c04). In version 8.0.30 the problem seems to be solved because the statement is executed correctly.